# XML DTD parent element same with child element

Tags: xml, dtd

in my xml:

```
<mother>
     <name>mary</name>
     <child>
          <name>Ali</name>
     </child>
</mother>
```

so in my dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT mother (name,child)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT child (name)>
<!ELEMENT name(#PCDATA)>
```

when i try to run the DTD, its said that my name already been declared. so how i should change in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You *don't need* the second `name` declaration. These three declarations:

```
<!ELEMENT mother (name,child)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT child (name)>
```

are sufficient to validate your file. Your DTD "says":

1. The `<mother>` element must contain a *sequence* of *one* `<name>`, followed by *one* `<child>`
2. The `<name>` element can contain parsed character data (any text, including nothing, but no tags)
3. The `<child>` element must contain exactly *one* `<name>`